# How to fix the ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: azure-sql-managed-instance

Unable to create a relationship 'FK_Sales_Date'.

The `ALTER TABLE` statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Sales_Date". The conflict occurred in database "SalesDataWarehouse", table "dbo.Date", column 'DateKey'.